# Bootstrap Carousel Not Starting Until Hovered Over Or Clicked

Tags: jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap Carousel Not Starting Until Hovered Over Or Clicked. Behavior cant be viewed at http://aagreen.dev.activemls.com

Here is my code:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators"></ol>

    <!-- Carousel items -->
    <div class="carousel-inner"></div>

    <!-- Carousel nav -->
    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON("/property/slideshow_json").done(function(data){
            //data is the array you expected.
            showCarousel(data, 0);
        })

        function showCarousel(arr, index){
            if(index >= arr.length) index = 0;
            var item = arr[index];
            //update the dom using the data item.mls_number, item.address, item.price
            //$(".carousel-indicators").append($('<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="' +index+ '"</li>'));
            $(".carousel-inner").append($('<div class="item"><img src="/property/photo/'+item.mls_number+'/1"><div class="carousel-caption"><h4>PRICED TO SELL | $'+item.price+'</h4><p style="text-transform:uppercase;">'+item.address+' <a href="/property/detail/'+item.mls_number+'"class="btn btn-small btn-info pull-right">View Details</a></p></div></div>'));

            //set the timer
            setTimeout(function(){
                showCarousel(arr, index+1);
            }, 500);
        }
        $('#myCarousel').carousel({interval: 4000});
    });
</script>
```

NEW CODE:
I attempted to simplify my code and still getting this odd behavior and it seems to be URL specific meaning that at say for example sandbox.dev.activemls.com the carousel loads fine, while at aagreen.dev.activemls.com the carousel behaves as described ie: not activating until hovered on or clicked on. Here is my new script:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
                      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                      </ol>

                      <!-- Carousel items -->
                      <div class="carousel-inner">
                      </div>

                      <!-- Carousel nav -->
                      <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
                      <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
                    </div>
                    <script>
                        $.getJSON("/property/slideshow_json", function(data){
                            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                                console.log(index, value);
                                $(".carousel-indicators").append($( '<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="' +index+ '"</li>' ));
                                $(".carousel-inner").append($('<div class="item"><img src="/property/photo/'+value.mls_number+'/1"><div class="carousel-caption"><h4>PRICED TO SELL | $'+value.price+'</h4><p style="text-transform:uppercase;">'+value.address+' <a href="/property/detail/'+value.mls_number+'"class="btn btn-small btn-info pull-right">View Details</a></p></div></div>'));
                            });
                        });
                        $('#myCarousel').carousel({interval: 4000});
                    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`showCarousel` isn't part of bootstrap as far as I remember or could find via search...and I don't see any other carousels on the page.

**My suggestion: comment out or delete this snippet in your original.**

```
//set the timer
setTimeout(function(){
    showCarousel(arr, index+1);
}, 500);
```

When I copied your code from between the relevant `<script>` tags, minus that block, the carousel started.

This advice is also supported by [the example](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#carousel) you based this upon where their code initialize the carousel with `$('#myCarousel').carousel();`.

Comment: still the same issue with that blocked out. showCarousel is the array from the JSON and then is used as a counter in the setTimeout function.

Comment: sorry this doesnt solve the problem...see edits above

Comment: That explains when I was watching the site, the array of images had grown to over 500 at one point.  Your image loader (`showCarousel`?) must have been running while I was on another page.  What if you use the 'slide' event as a way to add a photo to the end of the carousel?  There's a [post here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886233/utilise-the-bootstrap-carousel-slide-event-and-the-next-class) that discusses it and it could centralize all of your slide related code into one area, within the carousel `<script>` block.  You might also cut old slides, too, to keep the page size down.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".carousel-inner").append($('<div class="item active">
```

Add 'item active' hope it will work